# ExecuteReader requires an open and available connection VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create and save the profile details in my database, but I get an error that says, "ExecuteReader requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is closed. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's my code.

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Profile

    Public profileConnection As New OleDbConnection
    Public profileCommand As New OleDbCommand
    Dim anewProfile As New PlayerProfile()


Private Sub CreateProfileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CreateProfileButton.Click

    profileCommand.Connection = profileConnection
    profileCommand.CommandText = "select Email from Players where Email = '" & EmailTextBox.Text & "'"
    Dim profileDataReader As OleDbDataReader = profileCommand.ExecuteReader() 'getting error on this line

    If profileDataReader.Read() Then
        MsgBox("This email already exits.")
        profileDataReader.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Where do you call profileConnection.Open?

Comment: I don't think I called that

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: i know lol. its just a small project i'm working on. Nothing too special

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. To execute any command you need to have the connection associated with the command Open. This is done calling the Open method of the connection before executing the command. But before calling the Open method you should tell to your connection where is the database to open. This is done passing a "ConnectionString" to your connection

Adding to this your code has other problems that need to be fixed

```
Private Sub CreateProfileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CreateProfileButton.Click

   Using profileConnection = New OleDbConnection(... connectionstring...)
   Using profileCommand = New OleDbCommand()
       profileConnection.Open()
       profileCommand.Connection = profileConnection
       profileCommand.CommandText = "select Email from Players where Email = ?"
       profileCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
       Using profileDataReader =  profileCommand.ExecuteReader()     
       .....
       End Using
  End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```

In this code I have removed the global variables for the connection and the command and created them locally inside the click event. The connection, command and reader are enclosed in using blocks that ensure proper closing and disposing of the object. Finally the query text is now parameterized to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems.